# FIFO Modelling using Mailboxes

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to understand the following code for a FIFO using Mailboxes. I can understand most of it , but      `void'(FIFO.tryput(write_data)); // nonblocking write` and     `void'(FIFO.tryget(read_data) ); // nonblocking read`
 - What is the purpose of void'? I know what void is, but are  `void` and `void'` in the program same ?

```
interface fifo_channel_1 #(parameter FifoSize = 8, PtrSize = 4,
parameter type DataType = uniType);
DataType write_data; // packet coming from sending module
DataType read_data; // packet going to receiving module
bit fifo_empty, fifo_full; // FIFO status flags

mailbox #(DataType) FIFO = new(FifoSize); // FIFO is bounded mailbox

function automatic void Write (input DataType write_data);
 void'(FIFO.tryput(write_data)); // nonblocking write
 fifo_full = ~(FIFO.num < FifoSize);
endfunction 

function automatic void Read (output DataType read_data);
fifo_empty = (FIFO.num == 0);
void'(FIFO.tryget(read_data) ); // nonblocking read
endfunction 

modport sender (input write_data, // sending module's connections
output fifo_full,
import Write);
modport reader (output read_data, // reading module's connections
output fifo_empty,
import Read);
endinterface: fifo_channel_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `void'` instead of `void` will avoid warnings from simulators which generate them; otherwise, the 2 will behave the same.
According to the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section 13.4.1, "Return values and void functions":

> Functions that return a value may be used in an assignment or an
>   expression. Calling a nonvoid function as if it has no return value
>   shall be legal, but shall issue a warning. The function can be used as
>   a statement and the return value discarded without a warning by
>   casting the function call to the void type.
>
> void'(some_function());

`try_put` is a mailbox method which is a nonvoid function that returns a value of type `int`.